# Alarm doesnt go off when app is closed(Android Studio)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've been stuck on this problem for days. I want to set an alarm and then send a notification when the alarm goes off. works well when the app is open, but it should work when the app is closed too.

here's the code:

**Android Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".note.AlertReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" ></receiver>
        <service android:name=".note.AlarmNotificationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" ></service>
```

**AlertReceiver:**

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("done", "done"); 
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,AlarmNotificationService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**AlarmNotificationService:**

```
public class AlarmNotificationService extends Service {
    
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("done","done1");

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void setAlarm(Calendar calendar){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,REQUEST_CODE_alarm,intent,0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }
```

`setAlarm` is triggered after `TimePicker` dialog is closed. I won't add the time picker code because it works with the app open.

when the app is closed. `done` won't appear in logcat so I'm assuming that there `BroadcastReceiver` isn't receiving anything

Comment: How did you test when the `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` , and then the apps is close at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `AlarmManager` with `Service` therefore it is hard for me to understand why it works only in foreground in your case, but, what I can do is give you a working example that executes in both foreground/background.

From there you should be able to figure out the solution that works for you.

Again, keep in mind that we are not going to use `Service` class.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.example.name.Receiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Alarm.kt

```
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
val intent = Intent(context, Receiver::class.java)

// Used for filtering inside Broadcast receiver
intent.action = "MyBroadcastReceiverAction"
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)

// In this particular example we are going to set it to trigger after 30 seconds.
// You can work with time later when you know this works for sure.
val msUntilTriggerHour: Long = 30000
val alarmTimeAtUTC: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() + msUntilTriggerHour

// Depending on the version of Android use different function for setting an 
// Alarm.
// setAlarmClock() - used for everything lower than Android M
// setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() - used for everything on Android M and higher
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  alarmManager.setAlarmClock(
  AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(alarmTimeAtUTC, pendingIntent),
  pendingIntent
  )
} else {
  alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
  AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
  alarmTimeAtUTC,
  pendingIntent
  )
}
```

BroadcastReceiver.kt

```
class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        // We use this to make sure that we execute code, only when this exact 
        // Alarm triggered our Broadcast receiver
        if (intent?.action == "MyBroadcastReceiverAction") {
           Log.d("ALARM", "RECEIVED")
        }
    }
}
```

The code is in Kotlin, but you should have no trouble using it in your project or just rewrite to Java.